# NodeJS + mongoDB findOneAndUpdate array of array

Tags: node.js, mongodb

i have a collection like this:

````
{
"_id": {
    "$oid": "5ef51c1b8433890012d99ce6"
},
"setor": ["Escrita Fiscal", "Gerência"],
"atendendo": true,
"chatId": "5544999990@c.us",
"senderName": "Victor Barbieri",
"tel": "(44)9949-9999",
"avatarImg": "url",
"mensagens": [{
    "author": "554499493950@c.us",
    "time": 1593121828,
    "fromMe": true,
    "horarioBR": "25/06/2020, 18:50",
    "body": "``` INICIANDO ATENDIMENTO```\nBoa Tarde, Me chamo *Victor Barbieri*, em que podemos lhe ajudar hoje ?",
    "caption": null,
    "quotedMsgBody": null,
    "seen": true
}, {
    "author": "5544999990@c.us",
    "time": 1593121829,
    "fromMe": true,
    "horarioBR": "25/06/2020, 18:50",
    "body": "*[Victor.B]* 32",
    "caption": null,
    "quotedMsgBody": null,
    "seen": true
}, {
    "author": "5544999990@c.us",
    "time": 1593121834,
    "fromMe": false,
    "horarioBR": "25/06/2020, 18:50",
    "body": "Frio",
    "caption": null,
    "quotedMsgBody": null,
    "seen": false
}]
}
````

Using NodeJS im trying to update the last object of **mensagens** with *column*  **seen to true**  , i tried using findOneAndUpdate but im relative new to mongodb and nodejs, i cant get the "logic" for it..

My idea was to sort  *mensagens* by time (it is a unix time) so i can get the newest message and after get the newest message i can update the seen column to true..

what im missing ?

sorry for my bad english :/
I have something like this now:

```
return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
db.db("intranet")
  .collection(ATTABERTO_COLECTIONS)
  .findOneAndUpdate(
    { chatid: req.body.chatid },
    { $set: { mensagens: { "mensages.seen": req.body.seen } } },
    {
      sort: { "mensagens.time": -1 }
    }, function (err, r) {
      if (err) reject(r);
      else {
        mensagem = {
          seen: req.body.seen
        };
        avisarFrontEnd(mensagem);
        resolve(r);
      }
    }
  );
```

Comment: You use [array update operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update-array/), in conjunction with the _update options_ like `arrayFilters` optionally, of a [findOneAndUpdate](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOneAndUpdate/#db.collection.findOneAndUpdate) - to modify a specific element in an array.